Nuxt3 - Specify page at runtime
I'm trying to programatically change which page in the /pages directory matches at runtime.
E.g. there are two page components defined in the /pages directory:
/pages/index.vue
/pages/page-wide.vue

Nuxt automatically resolves the url :
http://<local-url>/page-wide to the page-wide component.

But what if I want to determine the page component at runtime.
E.g:
<local-url>/page-a needs the default page layout of index.vue

<local-url>/page-b needs the page-wide layout

Is that possible?
I've already tried to add a dynamic route via addRoute, e.g.
router.addRoute({
    path: '/page-b',
    name: 'page-b-route',
    component: pageWideComponent,
});

This works for the second navigation, but not for the first (e.g. if I'll go to the / beforehand and then open the /page-b it works).
Thanks!

I've managed to solve this problem with a plugin:
In nuxt.config.ts:
... plugins: ['~/plugins/route.ts'], ...
route ts can then use
const router = useRouter();
and then it's router.addRoute() function to add new routes. This all happens before the url is resolved and therefore loads the correct component.
